# What's the abstract noun for 'deserve'?

Tags: abstract-nouns

Is there an abstract noun for 'deserve'? If not, is there a criterion for words to have an abstract form?

For example, say I am creating a game where I need my character to gain some "Co-efficient of (abstract noun for deserve)" to access something.

Comment: What do you want to say and/or what is the context in which you would use it? Telling us that would go a long way about lending you a hand.

Comment: So, just to be clear, you mean something like **"deservingness"**, but possibly a bit snappier?

Comment: ***Merit*** or ***warrant*** or ***due***.

Comment: The formal derivative is *desert*, the OF participle of *deservir*, but it is not much used today except in the fixed phrase *just deserts*. *Deserving* would be the fully English derivative.

Comment: Most people spell and pronounce it _just desserts_, and remark that it's not very sweet. _Just deserts_ would be pronounced differently and mean "only arid lands'. English spelling marches on.

Comment: [deservedness](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deservedness)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this context, I think this would suit your character's description:

**Merit** - [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/merit)

> A good quality or feature that deserves to be praised
>   The quality of being good, important, or useful : value or worth

For an in-game character, **deserve** is too vast. You have to wonder how and why he **deserves** something (like to enter a new zone, or to get a new aptitude) before actually putting a noun on it.

See: http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-thesaurus/merit, **goodness**, **virtue**, **integrity**, **talent** are all features that could make your character deserve something.

Answer (score 5):

There is an abstract noun from 'deserve': 'desert' (Chambers). This is often encountered in the plural (e.g. "just deserts").

I'm not suggesting it (or anything else) for a computer game, but you did ask.

Comment: And it's the only on-topic answer here. Though as you say it wouldn't work well in OP's intended slot.

Answer (score 2):

**[Honor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/honor)**, in the sense of:

> respect that is given to someone who is admired

or

> good reputation : good quality or character as judged by other people

Depending on your audience, a "Coefficient of Honor" may have a nice ring to it.

Answer (score 1):

What about ***karma*** https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karma  which can be oversimplified to mean "good-action points which you build up to make it more likely that good things will happen to you in return".

Answer (score 0):

**Worth** — [ODO](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/worth)

> *noun* 1.3. High value or merit
>   *"he is noble and gains his position by showing his inner worth"*