# Are abstract nouns always singular? Or are there such things as 'plural abstract nouns'?

Tags: grammatical-number, abstract-nouns

'Abstract noun' is defined by [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abstract_noun) as follows:

> A noun denoting an idea, quality, or state rather than a concrete
>   object, e.g. truth, danger, happiness.

Are abstract nouns always singular?
Or are there such things as 'plural abstract nouns'?

Do any of these qualify as 'plural abstract nouns'?

> We all want to see this criminal get his just **deserts**.
>
> Levels of **earnings** are still rising.
>
> There's a chance it could rain, but **odds** are that it'll be sunny tomorrow.
>
> The judge awarded her $5,000 in **damages**.
>
> Please accept my **condolences**.
>
> When it comes to men, she prefers **brains** over brawn.
>
> No **guts**, no glory

### EDIT

In no way am I asking about these specific nouns, as the title clearly indicates. So please take these nouns simply *possible* examples of plural abstract nouns (if there are such things), and try to answer the general question about the existence of plural abstract nouns.

Comment: It's tempting to answer "They all are: check in a dictionary that labels noun usages as 'abstract'." But 'plural' is loosely defined. Etically plural (furniture was strewn about the room), formally plural (data is missing), and/or taking plural agreement (police were quick to arrive)? Why is it 'the probability is that ...' but 'the odds are that ...'? As is 'abstractness'. Are 'deserts' (your word) more abstract than 'earnings' (where some can still count the notes)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Unfortunately, no dictionary I know of labels things like 'abstract noun'. Also, by plural I mean "having a plural form" normally with the '-s' suffix, not being treated as plural.

Comment: I don't know of a dictionary that does so either. Why not?:) But "... no dictionary I know of labels things like 'abstract noun' " belongs in your question. You could check lists of abstract noun usages and then check that the plural forms are licensed by dictionaries. For example, 'Damages were set at $25 000' is standard usage. Whether or not the noun should be considered abstract is doubtless more opinion-based. Indeed, scholars do not seem to have come to a consensus hereabouts. You could look up other threads here debating whether the concrete / abstract model is accurate or even helpful.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Not to argue, but _if_ dictionaries label an abstract noun as such, my question is not only unnecessary but would probably be closed for that specific reason, of which I'm sure you're well aware. Now, I'm not really asking about the usage of any of those nouns shown. They are merely examples with which I'm asking the general question about whether abstract nouns can have plural forms, because most grammars only show singular forms of abstract nouns.

Comment: I'll take one example, but then I'll close-vote for lack of research. [Systemagicmotives.com/Positive Abstract Noun_Glossary](http://systemagicmotives.com/Positive_Abstract_Noun_Glossary.htm) includes 'desert' (and of course this is the noun from 'deserve') as an abstract noun. [A previous thread on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/331910/whats-the-abstract-noun-for-deserve) (David's answer) states that this is an abstract noun, usually used in the plural form. / But with metaphorical (brains) and experientially discernable at some level (greetings; hole) reference, the ...

Comment: question remains "What exactly is an 'abstract noun' / 'abstract noun usage'?" Some would merely class all your examples as 'plural-form abstract usages'), while others would feel compelled to research the literature.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Even from your own research, it's clear that most grammars don't even mention the existence of plural abstract nouns. And I think it's absurd to suggest that 'desert' in your first link is actually 'deserts', because 'desert' as a noun means 'a waterless, desolate area of land'. David's suggestion that it is _usually_ used in the plural form is wrong, because it is _always_ used in the plural form as most dictionaries have 'deserts' as a separate entry.

Comment: I'm trying to get across the point that the classification of all noun usages (let alone nouns) into disjoint sets 'concrete' and 'abstract' is considered a model that needs discarding by many. There are papers on this that have been mentioned on ELU before. / I was making it clear that 'deserts' as in 'their just deserts' and 'deserts' as in Gobi etc are homonyms, totally different words. One has to be careful to distinguish different words (and different usages, eg 'brains'). / AHD has 'often [plural]' for the word in question, but includes an example of the singular found in Shakespeare.

Comment: Wars have been fought over issues like this. Consider the issue of the Trinity, for instance. It's hard to get more abstract, but the issue of one or three is still the issue.

Comment: There are abstract nouns and abstract nouns. One would never (I see you coming, "never say never") see words like ***justice, equality (non-math meaning), goodness*** used in the  plural as they merely refer to a state or idea . But then, the abstract noun freedom or liberty are found in the plural, and as such change their meaning slightly. The freedoms we cherish/The liberties we take/BUT: the goodness in their gestures. That said, as far as I know, none of the OP's example are abstract nouns, (except maybe condolences, which has  no singular). And I have no theory for this, as yet.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are plural abstract nouns. Here are a couple (emphasis, mine ... come to think of it, **emphases** is also a plural abstract noun):

> **state** *noun*
>   1 The particular condition that someone or something is in at a specific time.
>   ‘the state of the company's finances’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/state)

- Frequency of positive **states** of mind as a moderator of the effects of stress on psychological functioning and perceived health
  [- by Richard Bränström, published in bmcpsychology](https://bmcpsychology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/2050-7283-1-13)

> **stage** *noun*
>   A point, period, or step in a process or development.
>   ‘there is no need at this stage to give explicit details’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stage)

- I was in the early **stages** of pregnancy
  [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/stage)

From the list of nouns you were "in no way asking about", *deserts, earnings, odds, damages and condolences* are plural and abstract. *Brains* and *guts* are metonyms of concrete plural nouns.

What makes an abstract idea countable is the same as what makes a concrete noun countable: an accepted boundary to its extent. A *pool* (of water) can be distinguished from an adjacent *pool* because it has finite dimensions (you can tell where one pool finishes and where another starts). Likewise, there's a logical extent to *ideas*, *states* and *stages*, etc: you can tell where one of those finishes and another starts. On the other hand, the extent of *air*, *water* and *flexibility* is, in each case, somewhat nebulous, so they are treated as mass nouns. They can be quantised, however, and it's typically the quanta that are counted - e.g. a *puff* of air, a *tract* of water, a *point* of flexibility. Sometimes, the mass noun is used as a metonym for the quantum (e.g. in restaurants: 'one water' for 'one *glass* of water'), but this is straying outside the bounds of your question.

The issue with *abstract* nouns may be that *extent* is a conceptual matter there. One can't take a ruler to it or build a box to contain it. Nevertheless, if the abstract noun does have an (abstract) extent, it is countable.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the existence of plural abstract nouns. Your own examples -- _emphases_, _states_ and _stages_ -- are all countable as in _two emphases_, _two states_ and _two stages_. I wonder how "a noun denoting an idea, quality, or state" could possibly be countable. As for _brains_ and _guts_ being "metonyms", I'm not sure whether they really are "metonyms", but regardless, they denote "an idea, quality, or state" (intelligence and courage) whereas their concrete noun counterparts don't.

Comment: @JK2 You're welcome. On countability: your own phrasing, "*an* idea", treats *idea* as countable. Just because it's not tangible doesn't mean it's uncountable. Likewise, just because something is tangible doesn't mean it's countable (e.g. water). On *brains* - we can consider the thinking organ (physical brain) being spoken of in place of the ability to think (intelligence) - that's an example of metonymy. Similarly for *guts* and *courage*, though I can do little more than guess at the link there.

Comment: I agree that tangibility and countability are not logically related. Regarding "an idea", I know this sounds confusing, but I don't think the noun _idea_ in _I've got an idea_ "denote an idea, quality, or state" (as defined by Oxford). I think it denotes an individuated instance of any such abstract concept.

Comment: @JK2 - I was referring to your use of *an* with your use of *idea* in "an idea, quality, ..." :) . If it was uncountable (e.g. *wastage*), you would leave out the article: "denote (*no article*) wastage" vs "denote *an* idea".

Comment: Like I said, I agree that tangibility has nothing to do with countability. So, _idea_, which is intangible, is usually treated as countable. But just because abstract nouns are defined as "denoting an idea (a countable noun)" doesn't mean abstract nouns can or should be countable.

Comment: @JK2 I think I see what you're asking about: how does one go about identifying 'one' of something so nebulous to count it? I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: So do you consider _idea_ in _I've got an idea_  to be an abstract noun? All the plural abstract nouns shown in the OP are NOT countable. You can't say _three deserts_ or _five odds_, can you? On the other hand, you can count _idea_ as in _I've got two ideas_.

Comment: @JK2 I don't think you can pin it down without reference to the speaker's intent. It's like the phrase "I've got it!" (meaning they've understood something), where the *it* they *got* isn't really 'countable' - if they understood two things, it's not idiomatic for them to say, "I've got them!". If "I've got an idea" is used in the sense of "I know, how about doing it this way ...", then *idea* is a *singulare tantum* like *deserts* or *odds* in your examples. If it's used in the sense of "Here's one idea; and JK2 has another", then you *can* have two or more ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Your question posits an exact correspondence of the abstractness/non-concreteness of a noun and whether it is countable. To define an abstract noun, the Oxford Dictionary uses three abstract nouns: idea, quality, and state. All three can form plurals. *Flour, luggage,* and *celery* are concrete, but not countable. How, then, can you support such a correspondence?

Comment: Shouldn't this be more like a comment than an answer?

Comment: Only if you think the rhetorical question at the end is a real one demanding an answer.

Comment: Even if that's a rhetorical question, your answer still fails to provide an answer to my question. And even if it answers my question, I have to point out that your "answer" deriving from your rhetorical question is based on your erroneous claim that _idea_, _quality_ and _state_ are somehow "abstract nouns" even when they function as countable nouns. True, they can be abstract and plural but not at the same time, I think. And _flour_, _luggage_, _celery_ being uncountable is a non-issue.

Comment: On the contrary, it would be incumbent upon you to prove that an idea, i.e., a purely mental construct, is not abstract or that somehow, having two ideas makes it less so. Honesty is an excellent quality, and while there are no "honesties," one can have any number of excellent qualities. If you wish to entertain a definition of abstract/concrete different than that commonly understood, then you are welcome to put forth your own taxonomy that would include honesty but not quality. Until then, however, the question of whether there are plural abstract nouns is answered with a resounding yes.

Comment: Now that sounds more like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. Here's how to know for certain that abstract nouns are always singular, despite their frequently plural forms. As given:

> A noun denoting an idea, quality, or state rather than a concrete object, e.g. truth, danger, happiness. [Oxford]

- If an abstract noun denotes an idea, it is singular because "an idea" is singular.
- If an abstract noun denotes a quality, it is singular because "a quality" is singular.
- If an abstract noun denotes a state, it is singular because "a state" is singular.
- If an abstract noun denotes a concept, it is singular because "a concept" is singular.

And so on. Then, there is the fact that *some nouns do not have any singular form*. Example: trousers. "I'm hanging up my *trousers*." may mean that you are only hanging up a single *garment*.

The abstract nouns whose singularity you question, just coincidentally happen to fall into the category of nouns which must be posed in plural form, in order to convey their meanings in appropriate context.

So being in *plural form* doesn't necessarily mean that those particular abstract nouns are plural, in the sense that they represent more than one idea. Rather, each one represents just a single *concept*.

There are also many abstract nouns which are not posed in plural form: childhood, stewardship, direction, forgiveness, etc. -- as with concrete nouns.

So in conclusion, there are singular nouns which are expressed only in plural form. And, ***all*** **abstract nouns**, regardless of form, **are singular**.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HS0rc9WiQ_8

(Singular and Plural Nouns)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fv1PrLsUlo0

(Cambridge author Peter Lucantoni in a training video on abstract nouns...)

UPDATE (correction): How embarrassing, I was wrong:

> Abstract nouns
>   Some abstract nouns can be used uncountably or countably. The uncountable use has a more general meaning. The countable use has a more particular meaning.
>
> Nouns of this type include: education, experience, hatred, help, knowledge, life, love, sleep, time, understanding.

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/about-nouns/nouns-countable-and-uncountable

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "all abstract nouns, regardless of form, are singular." For example, _odds_ is in plural form and is treated as plural as in _The odds are in our favor_.

Comment: A few words, though **singular in nature**, are made of paired or grouped items and generally **treated as plural**: scissors, pants, trousers, glasses, pliers, tongs, tweezers, **and the like**. Many are often used with the word "pair" as in pair of pants or pair of scissors. And some others are used as abstract nouns.

Comment: Just so you know, I wasn't asking about whether there are any abstract nouns that are "plural in nature", whatever that means. I was asking about whether there are any abstract nouns that are "plural in form".

Answer (score 1):

Ideas can be abstract, while nouns are always concrete if they can be used in a real (rather than imaginary) sentence.

The OED refers to concrete nouns that are used to produce an abstract thought (like idea, state or quality). People may refer to such tools colloquially as "abstract nouns", as a kind of shorthand, but that does not create a new class of nouns which no one can see, speak, write or hear. Words themselves are always concrete if they can be written down. What they mean is another matter.

Comment: That's right, it does  not create a class. And in fact, the classes would be: those than can be plural with a semantic change and those that cannot. Justice is only in the singular but freedom be either. Then, there are also some that only occur in the plural.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make any contributions to the scholarly discussion. I merely wish to recall a single usage that is moderately well known of a plural usage.
"We hold these truths to be self-evident..."